# Why $ \lim_{x\to \infty} -2xe^{-x/2}$ is $0$?

Tags: calculus

Wouldn't the limit go to infinity since x goes to infinity and $e^{-x/2}$ goes to $1$? 
Thanks.

Comment: Does $e^{-x/2}\to 1$? What is the value when $x=1000$?

Comment: Ohh so e^(-x/2) approaches 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without L'Hôpital's Rule: Let $f(x) = xe^{-x}$, and suppose that $f(x_0) = y_0$ with $x_0 > 2$.  Now let $x_1 = ex_0$, and observe that $e^{-x}$ is a positive, decreasing function of $x$, and $ex_0 > 2x_0 > x_0+2$, so

\begin{align}
0 < f(x_1) & = ex_0e^{-ex_0} \\
           & < ex_0e^{-2x_0} \\
           & < ex_0e^{-(x_0+2)} \\
           & = e^{-1}x_0e^{-x_0} \\
           & = e^{-1}y_0
\end{align}

In other words, multiplying the argument of $f(\cdot)$ by $e$ reduces its value by at least a factor of $e$, allowing us to make it an arbitrarily small positive number by repeatedly introducing additional factors of $e$.

The function in the problem is just $-4f(x/2)$, so it too vanishes to $0$ as $x \to \infty$.

ETA: Note that this requires one to establish the continuity of this function (this is not too difficult, and it is uniformly continuous for $x > 0$); otherwise, the above argument shows only that if there is a limit, it must be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use L'Hospital rule on $ \lim_{x\to \infty} \cfrac{-2x}{e^{x/2}}$

Answer (score 1):

You could apply [de l'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty } {-2x \over e^{x \over 2}} = \lim_{x\to \infty} {-2 \over {1\over 2} e^{x\over 2}} = \lim_{x\to \infty} {-4 \over e^{x\over 2}}  = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Fact: $e^x\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$ and $e^{-x}\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$

Comment: Is that sufficient?  After all, $1/\sqrt{x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ also.  It must surely be relevant that $e^{-x/2}$ goes to $0$ "faster" than $x$ increases.

Comment: You are right, but I am suggesting only the behavior of the exponential function in general, rate of convergence is the thing should be taken care of.